# Shopware 6 call api from backend

Tags: shopware

I am making a new backend page where you should be able to download an export.

I already got the the route and the export working. If I call my export action from curl with sw-access-key I get my download: `store-api/v3/_action/orderer-export/77f40024cfd448d9a90063a75dc9fb2e`

How do I make the download link with auth?

**Update**

I added a [service](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-service) and created it like:

```
vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-import-export/service/importExport.service.js
```

Also changed store-api to api in my DownloadRoute.php: `@RouteScope(scopes={"api"})`

Now I can use this new service to call my API and the the file contents as response. Still no download.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `\Shopware\Core\Content\ImportExport\Controller\ImportExportActionController::download` I finally got it.

Simply add `defaults={"auth_required"=false}` to your route:

```
@Route("/api/v{version}/_action/import-export/file/download", name="api.action.import_export.file.download", defaults={"auth_required"=false}, methods={"GET"})
```

**Security Warning**: If your download contains non public information you need to add a secure token or download link. Otherwise your download is free for anyone. Shopwares own ImportExport generates download links with a token. Have a look there.